# How would I connect a react-native mobile app to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

Suppose I wanted to make a simple react native app with just one button connect to a Django backend.  For example, when a user presses the button, it should connect to the server and return “hello world”.  I know you have to use a rest api, but how would the code look in the us and the .Py

Also, when you combine them, is it possible to use the Django user model, or are some features blocked when you use a rest-api like a @login_required.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: this question is too broad for SO but just look up django rest framework for creating a rest API out of django.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.